# Flutter web Instance of 'minified:eU<void>'

Tags: flutter, dart, null, hosting, release

I am building a Flutter web app, which runs flawlessly in debug mode, but whenever I try to run it in release mode or deploy it to the hosting I see a grey box.

I see this:
[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

As you may see, this is an alertDialog, here is the code of it:
class TeamDetailsDialog extends StatelessWidget {

```
final Tournament tournament;
  final Team team;
  final String matchId;

  TeamDetailsDialog(this.team, this.matchId, this.tournament);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData(buttonBarTheme: ButtonBarThemeData(alignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween)),
      child: AlertDialog(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF333D81),
        title: Text(
          "Csapatnév: ${team.name}",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        content: DefaultTextStyle(
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                child: Align(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, child: Text("A csapat tagjai:")),
              ),
              for (Player player in team.players) Text("${player.displayName}(${player.inGameDisplayName})")
            ],
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              child: Text(
                "Bezárás",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              )),
          Spacer(),
          TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Retrieving the match object from the Cubit.
                final Match matchWithoutWinner =
                    BlocProvider.of<TournamentCubit>(context).getMatchOfTournamentById(tournament, matchId);
                // Creating a new match instance containing the winner team.
                if (matchWithoutWinner is DoubleEliminationLoserBranchMatch) {
                  final DoubleEliminationLoserBranchMatch matchWithWinner = DoubleEliminationLoserBranchMatch(
                      matchWithoutWinner.id,
                      matchWithoutWinner.team1,
                      matchWithoutWinner.team2,
                      team,
                      matchWithoutWinner.parent1id,
                      matchWithoutWinner.parent2id);
                  BlocProvider.of<TournamentCubit>(context).setWinnerOfMatch(tournament, matchWithWinner);
                }
                else {
                  final Match matchWithWinner = Match(matchWithoutWinner.id, matchWithoutWinner.team1,
                      matchWithoutWinner.team2, team, matchWithoutWinner.parent1id, matchWithoutWinner.parent2id);
                  BlocProvider.of<TournamentCubit>(context).setWinnerOfMatch(tournament, matchWithWinner);
                }
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Text(
                "Beállítás győztesnek",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've found out that the grey box is the release version of the red screen of death. After that, I checked, none of the injected variables are null. There is only one problem in debug:
[image]

What could be the problem? Could this cause the issue and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the issue was the Spacer() between the two buttons in the actions list, removing it fixed the problem, without changing the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Something is overflowing out of the bound of its parent widget, check deeper in to your code, use expand only for row, column, flex.